# Nginx responds only in the local network, Flask app with Gunicorn

Tags: http, nginx, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

I set up my **Flask** web application with **Gunicorn** 20.0.4, **Nginx** 1.14.2 and **Supervisor** on my **Raspberry Pi** (Linux 4.19.97-v7l+ armv7l) in my local network. I have followed the tutorial as far as possible: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goToXTC96Co&t=2749s.

Everything seems working as expected, but only on my local network. But if I use any other server other than my local server to open the URL, the website not be available.

If I change proxy_pass mode, I get a response from outside the network, bad gateway or a header to big error.

**Supervisor Config**

```
[program:warteschlange]
directory=/home/pi/Dokumente/warteschlange
command=/home/pi/Dokumente/warteschlange/venv/bin/gunicorn -w 9 app_4:app
user=pi
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/warteschlange/warteschlange.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/warteschlange/warteschlange.out.log
```

**nginx/sites-enabled/ Config File**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.1.242;


    location /static {
        alias /home/pi/Dokumente/warteschlange/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/; #here runs gunicorn
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

**nginx/sites-available/ Config File**
The default file untouched, maybe this causes the problem

**ufw status**

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: What is the output of this command: `/home/pi/Dokumente/warteschlange/venv/bin/gunicorn -w 9 app_4:app`?

Comment: [2020-05-29 15:18:13 +0200] [18522] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-05-29 15:18:13 +0200] [18522] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your `Nginx`  proxy configuration.

Comment: thanks @srahul07 , but nothing has changed. The site is still available local, but not from the outside.

Comment: Check your supervisor logs and flask app logs generated by supervisor configurations.

Comment: Have you opened up your ports from your router and mapped them correctly?

Comment: I have set Port Forwarding to Port 80 and allowed the UPnP-Port, I also tried port 8000 wich should be the Gunicorn Port, but everything stayes the same....

Answer (score 0):

edit this line as the following:

```sh
command=/home/pi/Dokumente/warteschlange/venv/bin/gunicorn -w 9 --bind:0.0.0.0:your_flask_port app_4:app
```